# Collapsing One Pivot Field Among Many

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have a pivot table with a few fields, and I want only one pivot field collapsed. I can't seem to make it work, and so would like some help.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pr As Range
Dim pc As PivotCache


Set pr = dataSht.UsedRange
Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, SourceData:=pr)
Set pt = pc.createPivotTable(wb.Worksheets(shtName).Range("A1"), strPivotName)


With pt

.PivotFields("One").Orientation = xlRowField
.PivotFields("One").Subtotals(1) = False
.PivotFields("Two").Orientation = xlRowField
.PivotFields("Two").Subtotals(1) = False
.PivotFields("Three").Orientation = xlRowField
.PivotFields("Three").Subtotals(1) = False
.PivotFields("Four").Orientation = xlRowField
.PivotFields("Four").Subtotals(1) = False


With .PivotFields("Sum of $$$ (000)")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Caption = "% Total"
        .Calculation = xlPercentOfParent
        .BaseField = "Two"
        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"

End With
```

I'm looking to collapse the last field, Four.  Adding `.PivotFields("Four").ShowDetail = False` to the end of my first With gives me an application-defined or object-defined error. "ShowDetails" results in the same.

Alternatively, I've tried using DrillTo, though I didn't quite understand it, in the following capacity after End With:

```
Dim pi as PivotItem
pi.DrillTo Field:= "Three"
```

Again, I get an error. Object variable or with block variable not set.

Still wrapping my head around VBA, so if someone could help me out that'd be wonderful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! So for those users in the future who might have a similar problem:

I had to go up a level and specifically identify the pivot table because it just wasn't working in `with pt`

So, after the above code in my question, I added

```
pt.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium3"
pt.PivotFields("Three").ShowDetail = False

end With
```

Why it wouldn't work in my first `with` block, I have no idea, but at least it's working. My guess would be something along the lines of not being able to manipulate a pivot table until it's fully created. Maybe. *shrugs*

Comment: Hmm. This worked for me as well, I was trying to get it to work inside a `With` block to no avail. Thanks :)